# Is there a way to denote in search query that "omit length of the field" in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

The only solution for omitting the length of the fields is to put/change mapping of the document and re-indexing the whole data which I do not want.

Is there a way to ignore length of the field while querying?

Answer (score 0):

If the length filter is being carried out by the [Length Token Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html) within an analyzer then terms filtered out won't be in your inverted index.

So you will **not** be able to search for the missing terms using a query - you'd need to update your analyzer and re-index.